# R Question: ifelse producing unexpected results

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am new to R and am getting unexpected results while using the ifelse() function. Here is an example. Below is a subset of the data frame I am working with. After the last command, why does the example$Points column contain 12 instead of 2? I have tried this for many different values of example$Value and the result is always 10 more than what I expect.

Example:

```
example
     Question StudentID SchoolID Value Worth Answer Points
2926       18    101290    84386     2     2     Co      0
2927       18    100878    84386     2     2     Co      0
2928       18    100895    84386     1     5     Co      0
2929       18    100913    84386     2     2     Co      0
2930       18    100884    84386     2     2     Co      0
example$Points <- ifelse(example$Answer == "Co", example$Value, example$Points)
example
     Question StudentID SchoolID Value Worth Answer Points
2926       18    101290    84386     2     2     Co     12
2927       18    100878    84386     2     2     Co     12
2928       18    100895    84386     1     5     Co     11
2929       18    100913    84386     2     2     Co     12
2930       18    100884    84386     2     2     Co     12
```

I've been using the work-around of just then subtracting 10 from the column, but I would like to avoid this and get to the bottom of what is going on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the output of `str(example)` or `dput(example[2926:2930,])`?

Comment: Can you try that in a clean R session? I get the desired result when I try your code. Don't call the data frame `example` as that is an R function; try a different name. You can also simplify the code to use `within()`; if I have your data in data frame `DF`, `DF <- within(DF, Points <- ifelse(Answer == "Co", Value, Points))` will do the same as your code without having to repeat all the `DF$` bits (`exmaple$` in your case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that `example$Value` is a factor and you're getting the underlying codes instead of the labels.  I recommend taking a look at your data as soon as it's read into R to see what's causing your input method to treat those values as factors instead of integer / numeric.

Comment: Yes, you're right, they are factors. This answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea, because when I run this on my machine I get the right answer:

```
> print(example)
  Question StudentID SchoolID Value Worth Answer Points
1       18    101290    84386     2     2     Co      0
2       18    100878    84386     2     2     Co      0
3       18    100895    84386     1     5     Co      0
4       18    100913    84386     2     2     Co      0
5       18    100884    84386     2     2     Co      0
> 
> example$Points <- ifelse(example$Answer == "Co", example$Value, example$Points)
> 
> print(example)
  Question StudentID SchoolID Value Worth Answer Points
1       18    101290    84386     2     2     Co      2
2       18    100878    84386     2     2     Co      2
3       18    100895    84386     1     5     Co      1
4       18    100913    84386     2     2     Co      2
5       18    100884    84386     2     2     Co      2
```

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
example = read.table('data.txt', header = T)
print(example)
example$Points <- ifelse(example$Answer == "Co", example$Value, example$Points)
print(example)
```

Here's data.txt:

```
Question StudentID SchoolID Value Worth Answer Points
18    101290    84386     2     2     Co      0
18    100878    84386     2     2     Co      0
18    100895    84386     1     5     Co      0
18    100913    84386     2     2     Co      0
18    100884    84386     2     2     Co      0
```

Hopefully this helps. What happens when you print out the type of example$Value? Try this:

```
print( typeof(example$Value) )
[1] "integer"
```

If that comes out as a factor, then that might explain your odd results.